# Why DDMS can free memory by clicking GC button while GC is never automatically called?

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection, slideshow

I am making a slide show like application.

However, I found it will be auto restarted after 30 min of slide show.

Doing ps and I can see the *RSS* section is increasing everytime when switching pictures.

I tried to add `System.gc()` before loading the next picture, and even calling `Thread.sleep()` to yield the current thread. But the gc never happens...

I think I am **NOT keeping any useless reference** in my code, since if I attached it with `DDMS` and click the `GC button`, it will perform `GC` very well. And the size of *RSS* section is reduced to the level at the time the process started.

**The question is Why DDMS can free a lot of memory by clicking GC button but GC is not automatically called (just leaving the useless objects there)?**

Comment: Have you freed the bitmap before switching to next image and have you recycled the image view?

Comment: Yes I have called Bitmap.recycle() before System.gc() when switching pictures.

Comment: You can't manually force the GC to free up memory programatically in Java; not without some kind of hack. `System.gc()` is nothing more than a *request* to clean up; a request that can be ignored. Look into the documentation of this method. Why do you want to force GC? I feel the actual problems resides somewhere else. Forcing GC is what you find to be the solution to your problem (check out the XY problem); what's your problem and show us the relevant code please. You shouldn't have to force GC; manage your objects better and size your heap accordingly

Comment: @VinceEmigh if you doubt that my code has problem (keeps useless reference to some objects), can you explain why DDMS GC could free the memory?

Comment: It's possible using hacks. But it's not possible programatically cause you *shouldn't need to* do it. If you are having memory problems, chances are you either have a leak or you could be handling objects more efficiently. But you never told us *exactly* what your problem is. Yes, you can invoke GC from a profiler, but you shouldn't NEED to invoke GC in your application; the problem isn't "not being able to force GC"; you should ask yourself "why do you want to GC in the first place?"

Comment: Long story short: If you feel you need to force GC, then you have a memory problem and need to monitor object creation and dereferencing correctly, and pool when possible. Forcing GC is not something Java devs do, and if you ever feel you need to do it, please mention why. "Application will be restarted in 30 mins" is not a reason to manually invoke GC. I'm sorry, but I gotta give this question a -1 due to being asked many times (how to manually invoke GC) and bad formatting (you never tell us why you wanna GC). I would expect better from someone with 3.5k rep

Comment: I think my problem is just within the GC. Since invoke GC by DDMS really frees memory but GC is not automatically executed (GC could free a lot of memory but it just rest aside, why?). Mentioning "restart after 30 mins" is just to say the app is not "force closed" but auto started by the Android system itself which is also abnormal.

Comment: It frees memory, yes. But memory should not need to be manually freed; that's a sign that you aren't managing your resources well enough. If it restarts randomly, you should walk through it with a debugger to find out why. You should be asking "why is my application restarting?" instead of "how to manually invoke GC". I can promise you that your solution does not require you to manually GC. If you ask the right questions, you'll get the right answers. I suggest restructuring this question to better fit your situation: "Why is my app restarting?" with code and attempts at fixing

Comment: I have changed the question. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: The reason it frees up memory is because there is memory that can be freed. The reason why the GC doesn't do it automatically is because it's apparently not needed. **Ask "Why is my app restarting?" Don't worry about the GC.** You think it's the GC, but it's not, and focusing on that is gonna waste a lot of time. Ask about your ACTUAL problem. If it is the GC, someone will let you know. Worst case, if it is the GC, all you'd do is size the heap properly; still wouldnt manually invoke it

Comment: Are you saying the phenomenon I have seen by "click GC on DDMS and it frees a lot of memory" is NOT a process of GC? Can you explain why and what really happens to free my memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67603/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-robin).

Answer (score 1):

You can't force GC (or at least I don't know such feature on Android). As `System.gc()` states:

> Indicates to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector. Note that this is a hint only. There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.

If your app doesn't suffer from `OutOfMemoryError` then everything is fine. Otherwise, you have memory management problems and certain resources like images (and other memory hog objects) don't get recycled/destroyed properly.